# How do I add the Genymotion plugin to Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, genymotion

I am using latest version of Android Studio, and it does not have the Genymotion plugin in it's repositories. How do I add the Genymotion plugin to Android Studio ?

Comment: https://www.genymotion.com/plugins/

Answer (score 3):

**Follow the steps:**

1. Start Android Studio.
2. Go to:
   Windows and Linux: File/Settings. 
   Mac OS X: Android Studio/Preferences.
3. Select Plugins and click Browse repositories.
4. Right-click (double-click for Mac OS X) on Genymotion.
5. Click Download and install.
6. Click Yes.
7. Click Close.
8. Click OK.
9. Restart Android Studio by clicking Restart.

For more info Check here https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences / Plugins and click “Browse Repositories”, then search for Genymotion. Right click and choose “Download and Install”. Restart Android Studio and you should see a new icon in your IDE. Click the icon and it will bring up Preferences, and choose the path to the Genymotion application.

Answer (score 0):

open Genymotion app,

1. go to Settings -> ADB
2. select 'Use custom Android SDK tools'
3. select location of your SDK.
4. Restart Android Studio
5. Try to Run your App again, even if you can get the Icon on the menu, after installing the plugin, your Genymotion device will be listed as one of the target to deploy your app, usually the first device on the list before you have Android available virtual devices if you have any