Unable to find Genymotion plugin in Android Studio by searching its name
I want to add and install Genymotion plugin in Android Studio, but when I search its name, nothing shows up.IN addition, I could find its plugin file to add offline.
when I search the plugin name in Android studio, I see the bellow window:
[the print screen of android studio] (https://i.sstatic.net/GsYhq1vQ.png)
I tried the tips in this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34422050/how-do-i-add-the-genymotion-plugin-to-android-studio#:~:text=Go%20to%20Preferences%20%2F%20Plugins%20and%20click%20%E2%80%9CBrowse,should%20see%20a%20new%20icon%20in%20your%20IDE.

This question is similar to: How to install genymotion plugin in android studio?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
